# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observer android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver was not registered

Tags: java, android, android-listview, dynamically-generated

I am trying to add item in ListView dynamically.

It check the new entry in every 5 seconds and set it into list view.

This is my code:

```
public void T2TCheck(){
        try {
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    List<MessageDB> messageDBList = MessageDB.find(MessageDB.class, "read = 0");
                    while (true) {
                        if (StaticMember.IS_ACTIVE) {
                            try {
                                for (int i = 0; i < messageDBList.size(); i++) {
                                    list.add(new com.example.admin.chatsdk.Message("", messageDBList.get(i).getMessage(), "", messageDBList.get(i).getSent() + ""));
                                    CustomAdapterM customAdapter = new CustomAdapterM(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                                    lv.setAdapter((customAdapter));
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am getting an exception on this statement:

```
lv.setAdapter((customAdapter));
```

My exception is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observer android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver@21dbdb80 was not registered.
```

Here is the full log:

```
22/com.example.admin.chatsdk W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observer android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver@21dbdb80 was not registered.
04-05 21:32:19.657     507-1222/com.example.admin.chatsdk W/System.err﹕ at android.database.Observable.unregisterObserver(Observable.java:69)
04-05 21:32:19.657     507-1222/com.example.admin.chatsdk W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.BaseAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(BaseAdapter.java:42)
04-05 21:32:19.657     507-1222/com.example.admin.chatsdk W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:459)
04-05 21:32:19.657     507-1222/com.example.admin.chatsdk W/System.err﹕ at com.example.admin.chatsdk.Messages$2.run(Messages.java:152)
04-05 21:32:19.657     507-1222/com.example.admin.chatsdk W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Please guide me to solve this issue. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I was creating the `CustomAdapterM` object in a `for loop` as you can see in my question which is wrong**.

*Steps to solve the issue:*

1) in `onCreate` methode I created `adapter object` and set `adapter` to `listview`.

```
CustomAdapterM customAdapter = new CustomAdapterM(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
lv.setAdapter((customAdapter));
```

2) and call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` function after adding new items into the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < messageDBList.size(); i++) {
    list.add(new com.example.admin.chatsdk.Message("", messageDBList.get(i).getMessage(), "", messageDBList.get(i).getSent() + ""));
}
customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Expain what your answer is. What did you do?

Comment: sorry, I was new when I put that question. I edited my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't  following code be outside for loop? :

```
     CustomAdapterM customAdapter = new  CustomAdapterM(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
     lv.setAdapter((customAdapter));
```